# Deleting multiple rows in datagridview using checkboxes-string was not recognized as a valid boolean

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

please help me I stuck in datagridview in c# winforms where my sql table looks like below

```
empcode-varchar(50)
fullname-varchar(50)
month-date
branch-varchar(50)
designation-varchar(50)
id-varchar(50)
accountno-nvarchar(50)
paymenttype-nvarchar(50)
basicsal-int
ca-int
hra-int
sa-int
totalsalary-int
allowanceid-int(IDENTITY COLUMN)
remark-nvarchar(50)
```

For this table i took two buttons one is viewdata and another is delete
my view data coding part working fine and is shown below:-

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from allowance", cn);
            dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dg2.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dg2.Rows.Add();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false;
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["empcode"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["fullname"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["month"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["branch"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["designation"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["id"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["accountno"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["paymenttype"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["basicsal"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["ca"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["hra"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["sa"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[13].Value = item["totalsalary"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[14].Value = item["allowanceid"].ToString();
                dg2.Rows[n].Cells[15].Value = item["remark"].ToString();
}
```

and another button "delete" code is looks like this way:-

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow itemRow in dg2.Rows)
                {
                    if (bool.Parse(itemRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString()))
                    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM allowance WHERE allowanceid = '" + itemRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString() + "'", cn);
                        DataTable bb = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(bb);
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("SuccessFully DELETED.....!");
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm getting error-String was not recognized as a valid boolean

Comment: `itemRow.Cells[14]` is not a bool value, but integer, I think, so bool.Parse() generates the error.

Comment: @romanoza instead of that what i want to write..please i don't have a idea

Comment: What did want to achieve by writing `bool.Parse(itemRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString())`?

Comment: @romanoza To delete that particular records only because there are same multiple emp id's within this table so i choose to delete allowance id to overcome this problem

Comment: But why do you want to convert allowanceId to bool? This line: `bool.Parse(itemRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString())` tries to convert `itemRow.Cells[14]` to bool.

Comment: I'm getting error-bool.Parse(String) has some invalid arguments

Comment: But why do you call `bool.Parse`? Why do you want to convert string to bool? Why do you want to convert the string '123' to true/false?

Comment: I'm deleting records through checkbox so that's the reason

Comment: So, get the value from the checkbox, not from DataGridViewRow. Find the checkbox and get the value.

Comment: checkbox is inside the datagridview how can i get the value

Comment: In which column do you have the checkbox? Which index? itemRow.Cells[14] holds the allowanceid. But checkbox?

Comment: first column means itemRow.Cells[0]

Comment: You are using the wrong index. Just modified it this way : `if ((bool)itemRow.Cells[0].Value)` insted of `if (bool.Parse(itemRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString()))`

Comment: @Bioukh Specified cast is not valid-->error is displaying

Comment: And this : `if (itemRow.Cells[0].Value is bool && (bool)itemRow.Cells[0].Value)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow itemRow in dg2.Rows)
                {
                    if (bool.Parse(Convert.Tostring(itemRow.Cells[14].Value)))
                    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM allowance WHERE allowanceid = '" + Convert.Tostring(itemRow.Cells[14].Value) + "'", cn);
                        DataTable bb = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(bb);
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("SuccessFully DELETED.....!");
```

wire this code in DaataError Event

```
 private void DGData_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
        {
            if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
            {
                DataGridView grd1 = (DataGridView)sender;
                grd1.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error";
                grd1.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an error";

                anError.ThrowException = false;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Nehet-Still i'm facing same problem---An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow itemRow in dg2.Rows)
                    {
                        if (!itemRow.IsNewRow)
                        {
                            if ((bool)itemRow.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue)
                            {
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM allowance WHERE allowanceid = " + Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.Cells[14].Value) + "", cn);
                                DataTable bb = new DataTable();
                                da.Fill(bb);
```